# UK entry clearance recommended - still waiting for visa?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration

The visa was originally denied. The decision was appealed and a request for reconsideration was filed. Afterwards the appeal review team sent a letter noting the withdrawal of the original refusal. The appeal review team recommended to grant entry clearance at the beginning of last month. It was said that the decision making center would follow-up. But, the decision making center has still not made contact.

This seems to be taking disproportionately long.

How long does it usually take after the appeal review team has recommended granting entry clearance to hear back from the decision making center?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The visa decision making process is usually very well hidden from the applicant's view. I've never heard of separate review and decision-making teams before. Is there more detail you can add that will clarify?

Comment: I feel like this is an administrative review or other not-the-usual route.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass The visa was originally denied. The decision was appealed and a request for reconsideration was filed. Afterwards the appeal review team sent a letter noting the withdrawal of the original refusal.

Comment: @Mo. Please add this additional information into your question, using the "edit" button below the question text. This will make more likely that new readers of the question will understand the actual circumstances.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Done.

Comment: Withdrawing the refusal means you are back to the state when you applied for the visa. And you can be 99% sure that it won’t be refused for the same reason.

Comment: What visa are you actually applying for? Refusals on UK visitors visas don't generally have a right of appeal. If you're applying for a long-term visa you might do better to ask on [expatriates.se]

Comment: @Arthur'sPass The application is for an immigration EEA family permit.

Comment: @Mo. The folks at [expatriates.se] might have more experience with this - it's more their line. We only handle short term travel |here.